# How to disable the hint tab code in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net

[image]

How to disable the hint tab code in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Tools > Options.
2. In the options window, search for "C# suggestions"
3. Disable the "C# suggestions" option.